# Does it make sense to ask country specific questions?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that many of the suggestions are US centric (amazon, B&H links). This is true especially of equipment recommendation type of questions as the price and availability can vary greatly across countries.

To this end, I was wondering it makes sense to ask questions that are centred around a country\region?

Answer (score 2):

The suggestions/answers you get are inherently going to be linked to the countries / products that people are familiar with.  Whilst I don’t exactly see anything wrong with having questions like ‘Can you recommend a good XXX, I’m in country YYY’ my concern is that they may become overly localised to a moment in time / location and would therefore not be a good fit for the stack exchange format.  An equipment recommendation for a specific country that isn’t answered for a year because nobody else is familiar with the country is unlikely to be particularly helpful.

I think questions generally should be asked in a way that they can be answered and useful to people other than the individual that asked the question.  If you have relevant constraints caused by the country you are in then it may be worth mentioning them as part of the question.  This will allow individuals that are not familiar with your country but are familiar with your problem to answer in a way that is likely to be more useful.  I personally would prefer to have an answer that gave me something to look at / try to match with a local brand than to have no answer at all because nobody was familiar enough with my country to know what was available.